# A simple subclass of QWidget doesn't work as a QWidget

Tags: c++, qt

**I create a very simple subclass of QWidget like this:**

```
class WorldView : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit WorldView(QWidget *parent = 0);

signals:

public slots:
};

WorldView::WorldView(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent)
{

}
```

**I create an instance of it in main window like this:**

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

protected:
    virtual void resizeEvent(QResizeEvent* event) override;

private:
    WorldView* _worldView;
};

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent)
{
    _worldView = new WorldView(this);
    _worldView->setStyleSheet(QString("* {background-color : black}"));
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete _worldView;
}

void MainWindow::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *event)
{
    _worldView->resize(size());
}
```

But the widget does not show as expected.

I have tried to call `show()`, but it still doesn't show.

The weird thing is that when I replace `WorldView` with `QWidget`, the widget shows.

I don't know why.

Comment: Forgot to setupUI for WorldView?

Comment: @FreddyKay There is no UI file. So no need for setupUI.

Comment: What do you expect from `_worldView->resize(size());` What does `size()` return (or supossed to)?

Comment: @mvidelgauz Make the size of `_worldView` the same as its parent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Because stylesheets don't work that way for custom QWidget subclasses.**

From https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html :

> **QWidget**
>
> Supports only the background, background-clip and background-origin properties.
>
> If you subclass from QWidget, you need to provide a paintEvent for your custom QWidget as below:
>
> ```
> void CustomWidget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *)
> {
>     QStyleOption opt;
>     opt.init(this);
>     QPainter p(this);
>     style()->drawPrimitive(QStyle::PE_Widget, &opt, &p, this);
> }
> ```
>
> The above code is a no-operation if there is no stylesheet set.
>
> Warning: Make sure you define the Q_OBJECT macro for your custom widget.

(And, in general, stop using stylesheets.)

Comment: why "stop using stylesheets"?

Comment: They're expensive, buggy and unmaintained; basically a stop-gap and a quick'n'dirty way to customize look and feel. The only complete way to get non-native look and feel is subclassing QStyle. Moreover, people tend to abuse them even to get some basic effects (such as changing background color or similar, which can be obtained much more cheaply by changing the widget's palette or by a custom paint event).

Comment: hmm, i see. Though once I tried to change the looks of QTableView by installing a proxy style (which I tried to install on a "CustomTableView : public QTableView" class), and it just didn't work and I gave up. IMO there is only little documentation on how to customize style by subclassing QStyle.