# Qt How to change stylesheet of the widgetContents-widget of every scrollarea in mainWindow?

Tags: c++, qt, qtstylesheets

In Qt I can not just style the QScrollArea (I only want to set the background color), I have to style the widgetContents-widget of every scrollarea like:

```
// qss code
QScrollArea #scrollAreaWidgetContents_1, #scrollAreaWidgetContents_2, ...{
    background-color: MYCOLOR;
}
```

Question: How do I have to set up the stylesheet of mainWindow, that the widgetContents-widget of every scrollarea changes its background color without calling them all manually like in the example? Thanks for answers!

Comment: You mean like this ? http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qt-widgets-stylesheet-example.html

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use the widget's object names somewhere else, you could set a common object name for all of them:

```
auto* content = new QWidget();
content->setObjectName("scrollAreaWidget");
auto* scrollArea = new QScrollArea();
scrollArea->setWidget(content);
```

And then address them from the qss like this:

```
QWidget#scrollAreaWidget
{
    background-color: white;
}
```

---

If that is no option, you can try subclassing `QWidget` and apply the style for your new class. I haven't tried this approach, but [it seems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38958873/a-simple-subclass-of-qwidget-doesnt-work-as-a-qwidget), you might face some difficulties there.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Well I have to use the object names, so unfortunately no option. So subclassing seems to be the only option. Actually wanted to prevent that, but I think it will work